# PHP JSON Encode and JSON Decode

Tags: php, json

This is my json data, I want to do decode this json data and store the json data in any variable in php,
and also I required to encode this json data on PHP. please anyone can help me

```
    {  
       "code":0,
       "message":"sucess",
       "user_id":"1",
       "firstname":"mugunthan",
       "lastname":"ssss",
       "user":{  
          "fname":"mugunthan",
          "lname":"ssss"
       },
       "data":[  
          {  
             "add":"added",
             "sub":"subtract"
          }
       ]
    }
```

Comment: Use the `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` functions.

Comment: `$variable = json_decode($json, true);` - what's the problem in doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to use

```
$variable = json_decode($json, true);
```

Thats realy a simple one